# JavaScript Arrays "For Loop" prints only the 1st iteration

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, printing

JavaScript Arrays prints first iteration of the `for` loop in bulleted list `<ul>`, but not the 2nd & 3rd iteration. I have no host server; can not use plugin or jQuery; I am limited to use just HTML & JavaScript.

```js
var businesses = [

  business = [
    "Business1Name",
    "Business1Type",
    "Business1Address",
    "Business1Phone",
    "Business1Url",
    "Business1FB",
    "Business1Owner",
  ],
  business = [
    "Business2Name",
    "Business2Type",
    "Business2Address",
    "Business2Phone",
    "Business2Url",
    "Business2FB",
    "Business2Owner",
  ],
  business = [
    "Business3Name",
    "Business3Type",
    "Business3Address",
    "Business3Phone",
    "Business3Url",
    "Business3FB",
    "Business3Owner",
    "Business3Var",
  ],
];

var text = "<ul>";
for (i = 0; i < businesses.length; i++) {
  for (j = 0; j < businesses[i].length; j++) {
    text += "<li>" + businesses[i][j] + "</li>";
  }
  text += "</ul>";
  text += "<BR>";
}

document.getElementById("businessID").innerHTML = text;
```

```html
<h2>JavaScript Arrays</h2>
<p id="businessID"></p>
```

I'm a novice. Thank you in advance! Try code here https://www.w3schools.com/js/tryit.asp?filename=tryjs_whereto

Comment: `businesses = [

  business = [` Arrays should have *plain values* only, not assignments. (In the situation that you want key-value pairs, use an object instead)

Comment: can you show us the expected output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that you're only adding one opening ul tag at the start, but three closing ul tags inside the for loop. This results in the first list being contained by ul tags, but not the other two.

```
var text = "<ul>"; // This will create a single opening ul tag
for (i = 0; i < businesses.length; i++) {
  for (j = 0; j < businesses[i].length; j++) {
    text += "<li>" + businesses[i][j] + "</li>";
  }
  text += "</ul>"; // This will create three closing ul tags
  text += "<BR>";
}
```

To fix your issue, add the ul tag inside of the first for loop so that it gets appended with each iteration of the loop.

```
var text = "";
for (i = 0; i < businesses.length; i++) {
  text += "<ul>";
  for (j = 0; j < businesses[i].length; j++) {
    text += "<li>" + businesses[i][j] + "</li>";
  }
  text += "</ul>";
  text += "<BR>";
}
```

Your array is also non-standard (declaring variables inside the square brackets). You might want to look into using objects with key/value pairs instead.

Answer (score 0):

```
var text = "<ul>";
for(i=0; i< businesses.length; i++){
  for(j=0; j< businesses[i].length; j++){
  text += "<li>" + businesses[i][j] + "</li>";
  }

text += "<BR>";
}
text += "</ul>";
document.getElementById("businessID").innerHTML = text;
```

Answer (score 0):

An array is supposed to have values inside them. Not separate expression-like assignments. In case of needing key-value pairs use objects.

And just to answer your question... Place the `text += "</ul>";` outside both the for loops. It would give the output you're wanting.

But it's just not good practice to have separate assignments within arrays.